# Getting a count of employees in a company with jobs available in the company

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am trying to get the count of employees in a project but I am stuck on getting the count using the 3 tables. I am able to get the count of employees with the same job but I cant wrap around getting the "total" count of employees with those jobs in that project.

I have 3 tables

```
employees | job | project
```

The table employees_
looks like:

```
emp_id | emp_name | emp_job
   1       phil        1
   2       scott       4
   3       alex        3
   4       bob         1
   5       dave        2
```

The table job_
looks like:

```
job_id |  job_name  | job_req | proj_id
   1     programmer    cert        1
   2       manager      ba         1
   3       manager       n/a       2
   4     programmer     ba         2
```

The table project_
looks like:

```
proj_id | proj_name | proj_info
    1        dev1       lalala
    2        dev2       tralala
```

so the query should output

project 1 has a total of 3 employees

project 2 has a total of 2 employees

- edit more info added below i have also added some table data above.

i am trying to do this in PHP i have looked up a few examples online and looking at it now they weren't what i needed.

this is the query i am using to count employees with jobs but i need it to be # of employees for said project. I would use a WHERE but thats not how my tables are set up.

//
$jon = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`employee_job`) FROM ".DB_EMP." ");
        $emp = mysql_free_result($jon);

I was trying to expand this query using 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

with no luck because i now think thats now going to solve my issue.

Comment: You want a PHP solution or a MySQL solution. And can you please share the code with what you've tried.

Comment: what are the tables relationships?

Comment: julio i updated my post above is that what you are referring to as table relations? i populated the tables

Answer (score 0):

This may get you in the right direction..

Inner Join

```
    SELECT emp_id, emp_job, emp_name
    FROM employees
    INNER JOIN job
    ON table1.emp_job=table2.job_id;
```

Comment: hey thanks but not exactly what i am looking for i already know the amount of employees i have / know how to query that. what i am looking for is to find out how many employees i have assigned to a given project.

Comment: My apologies, to get you in the right direction you might want to do an inner-join/outer-join in MYSQL. This will allow you to pull multiple tables given a primary/unique key. 

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(employees.emp_job) FROM employees,job,project WHERE project.projid=job.proj_id AND employees.emp_job = job.job_id);
```

Comment: on my page i am getting Array as the display i believe i am not doing something right. this is how i an trying to make the value view able which im 90% is wrong on my end because i dont have the company id defined but when i try that it wont display anything. here are the 2 ways i have tried $test = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(employees.emp_job) FROM employees,job,project WHERE project.projid=job.proj_id AND employees.emp_job = job.job_id"); $testresult = mysql_fetch_array($test); i get a result of array. when i try it like this i get nothing - $testresult = $test['company_id'];

Answer (score 0):

took a different route to achieve the same result. I added an extra column to the project table and called it project_ecount "employee count". I then wrote a query to add (+)1 to the count each time an employee is added to a project and another query to subtract (-)1 if an employee is removed from a project.

query examples -

//add
mysql_query("UPDATE project SET project_ecount=$compu2+1 WHERE project_id=$compu2");

//subtract
//mysql_query("UPDATE project SET project_ecount=$compu2-1 WHERE project_id=$compu2");